# How to dump a pg db without direct access to the server filesystem/database

Tags: database, postgresql, dump

I'm trying to make a dump-like file just from queries (PG DB), to import on a local PG DB.

I only have access to the database through code, that means I can't even connect to it with a pgadmin-like software, so pg-dump is not an option.

I need to make a copy of the structure and data, but I can't seem to find a not so much time consuming way of doing that.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Define time consuming? If you don't have connection credentials, then you can query the information schema to get structure and then build queries to get data. There's no built-in functionality to get DDL, as far as I know.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was affraid of. Thing is I work on a very poor built javascript framework that access the database (the only way I can reach the data). And the tables are huge (not only rows, but columns also - almost every table has 300+ columns).